# Bash extract string between two patterns

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file containing three kinds of lines:

```
[       ]   APPLE
[ORANGE ] * ORANGE      on XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
[YELLOW ] + BANANA      on XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

What I want to do now is to extract the fruit name like below:

```
APPLE
ORANGE
BANANA
```

I tried to extract it with `echo ${line:start:end}` before I realized both the length of the line might vary. So I guess I have to do it with pattern matching.

I'm new to bash, how should I extract the fruit name, with sed/awk or any other ways?

Thanks!

Comment: what will be expected output from above 3 lines?

Comment: @josifoski, thanks for the reply, the post is updated

Comment: can there be more than 9 SERVICE entries, i.e. `SERVICE11 or SERVICE23 or SERVICE999999` (just for a few possible examples). Please update your question with this information, rather than replying in a comment thread. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Sorry for causing confusion, what I mean was the length of service name might vary, if that's your concern. I'm new to bash and to here as well, so thanks for telling me that! Post updated.

Comment: You need to explain the rules more in detail.  I expect the input lines starts with something inside square parenthesis ([ ... ]), followed zero or more symbols (+ *),  followed by some fruit names (NOTE: can fruit name contains two words, like "start fruit"?), followed by zero or more "on xxxxx"?   If your input ends with some garbage other than "on xxxxx", and you have to deal with two-worded fruits like "start fruit", how do I know the 2nd word is part of the fruit name or a garbage word, since garbage word can be something other than onXXX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This deals with the two-worded fruit names like "star fruit", but must assume that the trailing garbage (if any) starts with "on" (i.e. those "on XXXXXX"). It also assumes that the fruit name start after the first left-square parenthesis ("]"):

```
sed -e 's/^[^]]*][^A-Za-z]*//' -e 's/\bon\b.*$//'  -e 's/\s*$//' your_file
```

Explanations:

`-e 's/^[^]]*][^A-Za-z]*//'`:
   Removes anything from the start until first "]", the first "]", and any non-alphabets following the first "]".

`-e 's/\bon\b.*$//'`:
   Removes a whole word "on" til the end of a line, if it exists.

`-e 's/\s*$//'`:
   Removes any trailing spaces, after the above processing.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that the fruit name contains one word only. Anyway, this works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this sed

```
sed 's/^\[....\] . \([A-Za-z0-9]*\).*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` with extended regex `-E` and `-o` flag to return only matching bits

```
grep -o -E 'SERVICE[_0-9A-Za-z]+' file
```

The `+` will ensure that digits greater than 9 are still returned

**edited to match the changes in question**

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain the problem clearly, please check for the updates. Thanks!

Comment: since this searches just looks for strings that look like SERVICEXXXXX (inclusive  of underscores, numbers and characters), it does not really need to care about what happens before and after this string.

Comment: Actually what I meant there was $SERVICE_NAME, the service name can be anything with strings and numbers. I've updated the post again using examples, hopefully a better description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `awk` with custom field separator to get your values:

```
awk -F '\\[[^]]+\\][ *+]+| *on *' '{print $2}' file
APPLE
ORANGE
BANANA
```